# Proving that a $3$-dimensional compact polytope such that every two vertices are adjacent is a tetrahedron

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

> So I have to prove that given a 3-dimensional compact polytope such that every two vertices are adjacent, then it is a tetrahedron.

Somehow I'm able to visualise from the fact that every two vertices are adjacent and sees that it fits to the diagram of tetrahedron. Like it is a polyhedron composed of four triangular faces, six straight edges, and four vertex corners. From this it is suffice that every other vertices is adjacent to each other. But I'm not quite sure how to prove it.

Could you please help me in proving the above statement.

Cheers.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighborly_polytope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated, this is false; the [Császár polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cs%C3%A1sz%C3%A1r_polyhedron) is a counterexample.

If your polyhedron is stipulated to be topologically equivalent to a sphere, then we may apply Euler's formula of $V-E+F=2$. Suppose that our polyhedron has $n$ vertices. Then it has$\frac{n(n-1)}2$ edges, and at most $\frac{2E}3$ faces, because each face touches at least three edges and every edge is shared by two faces.

So we have

$$n-\frac{n(n-1)}2+\frac{n(n-1)}3\ge V-E+F = 2$$

It is easy to check that only for $n=3,4$ is this inequality satisfied, and as the $n=3$ case yields a degenerate polyhedron (two triangles glued back-to-back), $n=4$ is the only possibility, and only works if each face is a triangle.

Comment: @RavenclawPerfect just to confirm.. are you saying that it is not tetrahedron because you gave a counterexample and then are you proving why it is false?

Comment: I'm saying that the answer to the question you asked is "no", because there is a counterexample, but that if you add to the question "the polyhedron must be a topological sphere (i.e. no holes in it)", then it *is* true that it must be a tetrahedron, and I gave a proof of that fact.

Comment: @RavenclawPerfect oh! Thank you.